# Why am i getting Out of Memory Error in ifogSim, when increasing the total simulation duration beyond 5 minutes?

Tags: cloudsim

I am getting **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** error in iFogSim, when I increase the total simulation duration to 5 minutes and beyond. I am running the **VRGameFog.java** code

I have not made any changes to the default code yet. I have read to reduce the usage of static variables in the code.

Comment: Could you please provide any sign of code? 
I've worked with iFogSim and there's no such thing as "duration" in the whole **VRGameFog.java** code. You're saying you haven't changed anything in the code and you're getting OutOfMemoryError. I've tried the same code without changes and it worked pretty fine.